# How can I let the user of an Django Admin Page control which list_display fields are visible?

Tags: python, django

I have an ModelAdmin with a set of fields in list_display.

I want the user to be able to click a checkbox in order to add or remove these fields.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?  I've looked into Widgets but I'm not sure how they would change the list_display of a ModelAdmin

Comment: You might need to save the user's choices first, somewhere in DB, and then, override the **`get_list_display()`** method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I had to

1. Override an admin template (and change TEMPLATES in settings.py).  I added a form with checkboxes so user can set field
2. Add a new model and endpoint to update it (the model stores the fields to be displayed, the user submits a set of fields in the new admin template)
3. Update admin.py, overriding get_list_display so it sets fields based on the state of the model object updated